# find and modify a tuple value in array of [Int:(String:String)]

Tags: swift, tuples

I'm try to modify the value of the tuple base on the room number (103) to set from Y to N.
i'm try with .firstIndex(where..... but I don't know what to write...
any idea how to look inside the array numeroStanze and modify a specific value of the tuple from Y to N

thanks

```
let numeroStanze = [

    100 : ("Single Room", "N"),
    101 : ("Double Room", "N"),
    102 : ("Double Room", "N"),
    103 : ("Double Room", "Y"),
    104 : ("Single Room", "N"),
    105 : ("Single Room", "N")
]


func bookStanza (stanzaNumero: Int) {
    for (numeroStanza) in numeroStanze {
        if let i = numeroStanze.firstIndex(where: {numeroStanza}) {

        }
    }
}

bookStanza(stanzaNumero: 103)
```

Comment: In "array of", no. `numeroStanze` is a Dictionary, not an Array. Also, why use tuples? But `func set(newValue: String, forRoomNumber roomNumber: Int) { guard let tuple = numeroStanze[roomNumber] else { return }; numeroStanze[roomNumber] = (tuple.0, newValue)
}` should work with usage: `set(newValue: "N", forRoomNumber: 103)`. And `numeroStanze` is a `var`, not a `let`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, I think using a struct likes this is way cleaner and easier to reason about:

```swift
struct Stanza {
    enum RoomType {
        case single, double
    }

    let roomType: RoomType
    var isBooked: Bool
}
```

And then you can modify the value of the room in your dictionary by using:

```swift
numeroStanze[103].isBooked = true
```

Comment: I solved with: for (stanzan, _ ) in numeroStanze {
//        if stanzan == stanza {
//        numeroStanze [stanza]?.1 = "Y"
//        } else {
//            print("not able to book")
//        }

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
var numeroStanze = [

    100 : ("Single Room", "N"),
    101 : ("Double Room", "N"),
    102 : ("Double Room", "N"),
    103 : ("Double Room", "Y"),
    104 : ("Single Room", "N"),
    105 : ("Single Room", "N")
]

numeroStanze[103]?.1 = "N"

print(numeroStanze)
```